# How to get file type before requesting Apiko Api server for a file?

Tags: javascript, apiko

I'm using Apiko api server for a backend. When requesting a file, you send a get request to your api with `GET /files/:id`, then the server sends you the file itself. If I send a GET request to `/files`, I get all the files' details. What I need is a way to get the file type for a specific file ID before getting the file itself.

Comment: Get directory list, search for filename in that list, check extension, download or dont download

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: This question needs to be tagged with 'apiko', someone who can create tags please tag it.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting a file at the `GET /files/:id` endpoint will stream the file itself and the MIME type of the file is passed as the `Content-Type` HTTP header.

Requesting just information about a single file (including its MIME type) stored in Apiko without streaming the file itself can be done with the `GET /files` endpoint for example with a specific file ID:

```
GET /files?where={"id":1}
```

Comment: Thanks, @kaspi, That worked perfectly. one modification, id should be in quotes. GET /files?where={"id":1}